# ui-router: Transform parameter from URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

Is there any possibility to transparently transform URL parameters? As it's kind of difficult to explain, I will give a scenario. We have a URL structure similar to this one:

```
/shopping/nuts/:productId
/shopping/berries/:productId
/shopping/juice/:productId
```

Our products shown in the app (delivered by some API) might look something like this:

```
{ type: 'berry', price: 123, text: 'lorem ipsum', id: '12345' }
```

Note the discrepancy between singular and plural form: The URL contains the plural, e.g. *'berries'*, whereas the products as delivered by our REST API use the singular form *'berry'*.

Part from our state definition looks something like this:

```
.state('shop.product', {
  url: '/shopping/:type/:productId',
  templateUrl: 'type.html',
  controller: 'TypeController'
})
```

Problem: In every controller I need to invoke a function for transforming the `$state` parameter to the singular form (`toSingular($stateParams.type)`), and when building links, I need to do the same thing in reverse. This is extremely tedious and error prone.

So, my ideal solution would be something like

For URL `/shopping/berries/12345` I will have a `$stateParams.type === 'berry'`, and when creating the URL through `ui-sref="shop.product({type: 'berry', id: '12345'})"` I will get the URL `/shopping/berries/12345` again.

I've been banging my head on the table while trying to find a hook where I could integrate this logic without any success. Any feedback greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you hook into `$stateChangeStart`and redirect there?

Comment: @adamdport This would solve halfway of my issue. The problem is, that I cannot transparently transform values back, when building URLs from states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You want to register a custom parameter type.

https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/url.urlmatcherfactory.html#type

Your parameter type should encode and decode the value in the URL.

To `encode`, take the internal representation (`nut`, `berry`, etc) and return the string to show in the URL.

To `decode`, take the string from the URL and return the internal value.

```
 var productTypes = {
    berry: ['berries', 'berry'],
    nut: ['nuts', 'nut'],
    juice: ['juice'],
  }

  $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('productType', {
    encode: val => 
      productTypes[val][0],
    decode: string =>
      Object.keys(productTypes).find(key => productTypes[key].indexOf(string) !== -1),
  });
```

Here's a plunker that demonstrates the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/Eed8h7U6x0j8RAWs7qT9?p=preview

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

If your URL is `/shopping/berries/12345` that means you didn't pass `stateParams.type`. Beacause if you pass `type`, the url definitely `shopping/berry/12345`. and If you make url `shop.product({type: 'x', id: '12'})` the url will be `shopping/x/12`. That is what `stateParams` in the url. I think you are making url that is not a state. Thats why you are remains at the same url. Include `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()` to get more clarification.

```
$stateProvider.state('shop', {
  url: 'shopping'
})
.state('shop.product', {
  url: '/:type/:id'
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

If you make a wrong url, then you will be redirected to '/'

Comment: Thanks, however I'm not sure whether I understood you correctly: My central issue is, that I need to transform values as shown in the URL to a different value available via `$stateParams`. So I don't currently see how this could help?